# Colors on sets $S=\{1,2 \cdots ,1000\}$.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

To each element of  sets $S=\{1,2 \cdots ,1000\}$ a color is assigned. Suppose that for any two elements $a$ and $b$, of $S$,if $15$ divides $a+b$, then they both are assigned with same color. What is the maximum possible number of distinct colors used?

Please provide some hints.

Comment: feel free to edit title if its not appropriate.

Comment: Both which numbers? $15$ and $a+b$ or $a$ and $b$? $a,b$ can be of any color?

Comment: I think you need to pair up the residue classes modulo 15 that add up to 15...

Answer (score 3):

One hint: If $a\equiv b\pmod{15}$, then choose some $c\equiv -a\pmod{15}$ -- this can easily be done with $c\in S$. Then $a$ and $c$ must have the same color, and $c$ and $b$ must also have the same color. Thus within each residue class only one color can be used -- and sometimes different residue classes also need to share one color.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: what is the maximum number of colors we can use for $\{1,2\dots 15\}$?

If $a$ is green, must $a+15$ be green?